# Why does this proxypass affect all domain?

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04, proxypass

I'm running Apache, and have a `.conf` file as a `site-enabled` in apache as below.

```
<Virtualhost blog.example.com:80>
  ServerName blog.example.com
  ServerAdmin admin@example.com
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPass        /phpmyadmin !
  ProxyPass        /  http://localhost:2368/
  ProxyPassReverse /  http://localhost:2368/
</Virtualhost>
```

As you can see, I only want hits to `blog.example.com` to be processed by the ProxyPass command.
However, it is actually affecting all other domains `example.com`, `other.example.com`.

Am I missing something here?

If that's how ProxyPass works, is there any way to tell it to ignore physical files and directories if it detects one?

Other sites enabled (only one site runs under ruby, the rest follows the first form):

```
<VirtualHost other.example.com:80>
  ServerName other.example.com
  ServerAdmin admin@example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/other
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>


<Virtualhost other2.example.com:80>
  ServerName other2.example.com
  ServerAdmin admin@example.com

  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/rails/other2/public
  <Directory /var/www/html/rails/other2/public>
  AllowOverride all
  Options -MultiViews
  Require all granted
  </Directory>
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  PassengerUser www-data
  PassengerAppEnv production
  PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/wrappers/ruby
</Virtualhost>
```

Comment: Please post the config files of the other virtual hosts or sites that you have enabled. If you are using Apache 2.2.x you need a `NameVirtualHost` directive as well.

Comment: Hi. Updated configs of other sites. I'm on Apache 2.4.7 btw.

Comment: And all the hostnames resolve to the same IP address (both externally and locally on the server)?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm not sure what you mean by externally and locally, but there's only 1 server involved, so there's only 1 IP here.

Comment: It is not best practice to give the hostname in the virtual host definition. See Apache Docs -- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#virtualhost. Also do you have multiple IP addresses on the server?

Comment: I just wanted to confirm whether you have, say for example an entry in the `/etc/hosts` file pointing any of the hostnames to a different IP address which would take precedence on the server. You also need a `ServerAlias mydomain.com` in the virtual host that need to serve requests for `mydomain.com`

Comment: I had some problems when I used `*:80` previously. Don't remember what was it. I see, I only have 1 IP. I'll add the `ServerAlias` now.

Comment: Its working now. I changed all hostnames in `<Virtualhost>` back to `*:80` instead. `ServerAlias` doesn't help. Maybe you would like to write that as the answer?

Comment: @resting People get tripped up by the wildcard setup since you must make sure EVERY single config in your virtual host setup uses wildcards. If you have even one config that uses a hostname or an IP address, it can turn things confusing. But once you use wildcards, things are far smoother on many levels. Posted an answer with my take on it as well as my preferred `mod_proxy` setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [not best practice](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#virtualhost) to use the FQDN in the `VirtualHost` definition, it can cause unexpected issues such as this. I am guessing some of the hostnames resolve within the server to an IP address different from the one to which the requests are sent. This could prevent Apache from matching the right virtual host.

So the `VirtualHost` definition can be changed as below for all virtual hosts so we can be sure Apache matches the right name based virtual host.

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
     or
<VirtualHost [insert public IP here]:80>
```

Another point to note is that, if you want requests to `example.com` served by a virtual host other than the default one, you need a `ServerAlias mydomain` directive.

This page has more details on how name-based virtual hosts work -- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your configs like this. Note the wildcards I set for the [`VirtualHost`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#virtualhost) directive. It is best practice to just wildcard (`*`) the `VirtualHost` directive. Also I set a `ServerAlias` as well as spaced out & formatting the configs for easier readability who is helpful when debugging issues like this. Also, I set the `mod_proxy` config to more closely match a standard formula I like to use for this stuff.

Also, check the output of your virtual host setup by running `sudo apachectl -S` to see what you can see.

```
<Virtualhost *:80>

  ServerName blog.example.com
  ServerAlias blog.example.com
  ServerAdmin admin@example.com

  <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy *>
      AddDefaultCharset off
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass        /phpmyadmin !
    ProxyPass        /  http://localhost:2368/
    ProxyPassReverse /  http://localhost:2368/

  </IfModule>

</Virtualhost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName other.example.com
  ServerAlias other.example.com
  ServerAdmin admin@example.com

  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/other

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<Virtualhost *:80>

  ServerName other2.example.com
  ServerAlias other2.example.com
  ServerAdmin admin@example.com

  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/rails/other2/public

  <Directory /var/www/html/rails/other2/public>
    AllowOverride all
    Options -MultiViews
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

  PassengerUser www-data
  PassengerAppEnv production
  PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/wrappers/ruby

</Virtualhost>
```